# React Router history.goBack doesn't work when using <Redirect />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In a `React` App, I use `Router` like this:

```
let path='/';
if(condition){
   path='/dashboard'
}else if(condition){
   path='/login'
}

<Router>
 <Redirect to={path} />
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/dashboard"><Dashboard /></Route>
      <Route path="/login"><Login /></Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

This works fine. But I want to implement a `Back Button` in each page to move along pages. I do this:

```
// The login.jsx component
function Post(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => props.history.goBack()}>
        Go back
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined
```

Then I follow another approach. I use `useHistory`:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Link,
  useHistory,
} from "react-router-dom";

// The login.jsx component
function Post(props) {
  let history = useHistory();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
        Go back
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this time when I click on the `Go Back` button, nothing happens!

If I do this procedures with `<Link/>` it works fine. But when I use `<Redirect />` approach, it doesn't work. is there any alternative to my redirect approach? or is there any solution to current approach? thanks.

Comment: The way of using ```useHistory()``` is correct but the problem is you have to fill the history stack in order for ```goBack()``` to work. If there is nothing in the stack, ```goBack()``` goes nowhere. So you have to first ```push``` your redirects to Router history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For redirects to be included in the history, use `push`

```
<Redirect push to={path} />
```

[More information here from the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)